# How convert SQL Server DATE columns to DD:MM:YY and HH:MM:SS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server column which is called `DATE` with this sample data  19452801102747.

I have this code

```
 SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(10), [DATE], 103), '/', '')
```

I can get the date okay, is the final part of converting `HH:MM:SS`.

I am using SSMS 2018 and I would like to have two column separate; columns as shown on below image (DATE(DD:MM:YYYY))(TIME(HH:MM:SS))

Many thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you share your code that is not producing the desired output?

Comment: A sane schema would convert these to DateTime columns... but there is no such thing as SQL 2018, so it would be nice to know what DB you're actually using.

Comment: Whose smart idea was it to set datetime as a varchar?

Comment: What format is your date, exactly? YYYYMMDDHHMMSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**We can use a simple substring to add date time separator in your varchar string,
because we cannot directly convert varchar to datetime..**

```
DECLARE @date varchar(50) = '19452801102747' declare @date1 varchar(50)
SET
    @date1 = SUBSTRING(@date, 1, 4) + '-' + substring(@date, 7, 2) + '-' + substring(@date, 5, 2) + ' ' + substring(@date, 9, 2) + ':' + substring(@date, 11, 2) + ':' + substring(@date, 13, 2)
SELECT convert(datetime, @date1)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all: You should not store datetime values in a non-appropriate datatype.

Your example looks like `YYYYddMMHHmmss`. There is no *out of the box* conversion for this...

The following will perform a number of string methods in order to transform your own format to a standard format. In this case I chose ISO8601, which is `YYYY-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`:

```
DECLARE @YourDate VARCHAR(100)='19452801102747';
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,STUFF(LEFT(@YourDate,4) + STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(SUBSTRING(@YourDate,7,1000),7,0,':'),5,0,':'),3,0,'T'),1,0,'-'),8,0,'-' + SUBSTRING(@YourDate,5,2)),126);
```

The `STUFF()` calls will insert some characters in the right position. Furthermore some string cutting will swap your ddMM to MMdd.